# use not working in require classes

Tags: php, symfony

I created class named `Task` in the `App\Entity` namespace and my problem is in my another class I want to use it but it doesn't detect my class and give me error:

> Attempted to load class "Task" from namespace "App\Entity".
>      Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

this my `Task.php`:

```
namespace App\Entity;

class Task
{
    protected $task;

    public function getTask()
    {
        return $this->task;
    }

    public function setTask($task)
    {
        $this->task = $task;
    }
}
```

This is my `DefaultController` that uses the `Task` class:

```
use App\Entity\Task;

class DefaultController
{

}
```

Comment: Could you maybe add where each class is relative to your project root. I expect it's `src/Entity/Task.php` and `src/Controller/DefaultController.php`? Could you maybe post the stack trace along with the error message? The code looks right, so I want to make sure the problem is not actually somewhere else.

Comment: And can you confirm that you are actually using the Symfony framework?  Maybe post a bit more of the controller including the namespace and the $task = new Task(); line

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your autoloader settings, if you are using composer, you can have it such that autoloading only happens from the pre-built class map - called 'authoritative classmap' (https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md).

So, when you add a class to your source, it isn't recognised by the pre-built autoloader. Try running `composer dump` to let the autoloader load via standard PSR-0/PSR-4 rules.

If you are using the autoloader on PSR-0/PSR-4 mode, then maybe you've not put the file in the right directory.